# Using spread to add an object that I get from API into my initial datasource

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, spread-syntax

I do have an initial datasource:

```
const initState = {
  columns: [
    {
      id: 'column-2',
      title: 'column-2',
      tabs: []
    }
  ],
  columnOrder: ['column-2']
};
```

Once application loads (this is a chrome extension I am building for myself), I am getting opened tabs from chrome and would like to add them into this datasource as a new column.

Here's my attempt to do it:

```
export default (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TABS_LOAD:
      return {
        columns: [
          { id: 'chromeTabs', title: 'chromeTabs', tabs: action.payload },
          ...state.columns
        ],
        columnOrder: [{"chromeTabs"}, ...state.columnOrder]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I expect to create a data object like below by above function:

```
const state = {
 columns: [
 {
      id: 'chromeTabs,
      title: 'chromeTabs',
      tabs: 
[tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4]
    }, 
    {
      id: 'column-2',
      title: 'column-2',
      tabs: []
    }
  ],
  columnOrder: ['chromeTabs', 'column-2']
}
};
```

Unfortunately this has not worked for me. I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: What are you expecting the resulting redux state to look like?

Comment: *"Unfortunately this has not worked for me..."* In what way? Always quote any error message, etc., you're getting, or what behavior you're seeing that doesn't match what you expect.

Comment: Also, I don't believe `{"chromeTabs"}` is a valid syntax of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{"chromeTabs"}` is a syntax error. To add to the `columnOrder` array, just use `"chromeTabs"` without `{}` around it:

```
return {
  columns: [
    { id: 'chromeTabs', title: 'chromeTabs', tabs: action.payload },
    ...state.columns
  ],
  columnOrder: ["chromeTabs", ...state.columnOrder]
  // No {} -----^-----------^
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const initState = {
  columns: [
    {
      id: 'column-2',
      title: 'column-2',
      tabs: []
    }
  ],
  columnOrder: ['column-2']
};

const TABS_LOAD = "tabs-load";

const f = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TABS_LOAD:
      return {
        columns: [
          { id: 'chromeTabs', title: 'chromeTabs', tabs: action.payload },
          ...state.columns
        ],
        columnOrder: ["chromeTabs", ...state.columnOrder]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

console.log(f(initState, {type: TABS_LOAD}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me do a little bit more digging, based on your code, mine should work too, however my console.log shows me the exact same result.

Comment: @ilteris - Again, `{"chromeTabs"}` where a value is expected is a syntax error, so the code containing it will never run (because it can't be parsed at all).